# Refresh Angular JS Factory without page Re-load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, angularjs-factory

I'm accessing data stored in local storage through factory in angularjs. On page load the factory loads and accesses data from local storage and stores them in variables. I'm able to call that factory and fetch the value in the variables.

However whenever I call the factory after localstorage values have been changed the factory returns the old value instead of the new value. Is there a way to refresh the factory so that it again fetches the local storage values without refreshing the entire page?

Javascript Code..

```
headerApp.factory('userFactory', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    var dataFactory = {};
    dataFactory.user = localStorage.getItem("valueA");
    dataFactory.userName = localStorage.getItem("valueB");
    dataFactory.userAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("valueC");
    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

On calling userFactory.user, userFactory.userName after a function changes localstorage values returns old values instead of new ones. Please Help

Comment: As long as your local storage value gets changed and later whenever you try to access that values through factory/service its suppose to be take newly updated values. If its not theb I'm not sure I understood your point completely.

Comment: And yeah you could store your local storage value whenever its change and set it into factory and then try to access

Comment: Well, you can have an update method in factory which gets the latest data from local storage and update variables. You can call this method whenever you update local storage.

Comment: Why do you update the data directly through localStorage, not through the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving the code where you are pulling info from your local storage into a function in the factory, and then any time you update any of the local storage, you call that function to update the `dataFactory` too?

```
headerApp.factory('userFactory', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  var dataFactory = {};

  this.updateUser();
  this.updateUserName();
  this.updateAccessToken();

  updateUser () {
    dataFactory.user = localStorage.getItem("valueA");
  }

  updateUserName () {
    dataFactory.userName = localStorage.getItem("valueB");
  }

  updateUserAccessToken () {
    dataFactory.userAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("valueC");
  }

  return dataFactory;
}]);
```

And then at any point, say the user name got changed on the local storage end, you can call `this.userFactory.updateUserName();` to update `dataFactory.userName`.